# Reconhecer padrões de cores com OpenCV

Tags: imagem, opencv

estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo de visão computacional para futebol de robôs. Comecei a aprender OpenCV faz pouco tempo. E estou com uma dúvida na seguinte parte:
[image]

Gostaria de saber, como eu posso fazer a divisão de cada jogador de acordo com os seus padrões de cores. Eu consigo reconhecer as cores, mas não consigo isolar por robô (Área Preta).
Obrigado!

Comment: Alvaro, por favor seja mais claro. O que quer dizer com "isolar por robô"? Acho que você precisa começar com uma tarefa de nível menos alto. Tente quebrar mais o problema e vamos tentar ajudá-lo.

Comment: Realmente, não está clara a sua dificuldade (o que é "isolar por robô"?). Desistiu da pergunta?